# python: Delete all SMS from tasker with SL4A

Tags: python, sl4a, tasker

I'm trying to delete all text messages, both sent and received from Tasker on an Android Galaxy S4 
M919 Rooted

from tasker, by saving it as a .sh file in Sdcard/sl4a

What is the code needed to put in SL4A Script, for Tasker to find?

so far I have been trying the following:

```
import andriod
droid = andriod.Android()
msgis = droid.smsGetMessageIds(False).result
for id in msgis:
    droid.smsDeleteMessage(id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would spell the word "android" and the "droid" variable correctly to begin with ;-)

As for your issue, I'm also looking for a way to get my phone reacting to secret SMS commands using Tasker.

A few things to look at:

- Sending an SQLite3 command to mark message as read
- Opening the Messaging app for 1 second then closing it to remove the notification.